# How to search a specific set of columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, search

I have a dataframe as below

```py
  CHROM        POS FORMAT HG02317 HG03195 HG01959 HG03197
chr1  241663902     GT     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/1
chr1  241663902     GT     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0
chr2   47641559     GT     0/1     0/1     0/0     0/0
chrX    47641559    GT  1   0   1   0
```

I tried to use

filtered= df[df['HG02317'].str.contains("0/1|1")]

but this removes all other rows which still contains 0/1|1. I want to check all columns from iloc[3:] for 0/1 or 1 and then delete it if not present. Also, as column names from [3:] keeps varying i cant use the below as well though it works
filtered= df.query('HG02317== "0/1" | HG01959 == "0/1"')

Which means i want to search by col index
Using index ,
filtered= df[(df.loc[:, 3:] == '0/1')] gives error.

My expected Output is:

```py
  CHROM        POS FORMAT HG02317 HG03195 HG01959 HG03197
chr1  241663902     GT     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/1
chr2   47641559     GT     0/1     0/1     0/0     0/0
chrX    47641559    GT  1   0   1   0
```

Is there any work around for this in pandas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add to question how looks expected output from your data in question?

Comment: My apologies for the same. Have edited the problem, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select all columns with omit first 3 use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), then compare by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and test by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) all rows if at least one value match:

```
#added 1 like string or 1 like number
filtered = df[df.iloc[:, 3:].isin(['0/1', '1', 1]).any(axis=1)]
print (filtered)
  CHROM        POS FORMAT HG02317 HG03195 HG01959 HG03197
0  chr1  241663902     GT     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/1
2  chr2   47641559     GT     0/1     0/1     0/0     0/0
3  chrX   47641559     GT       1       0       1       0
```

Comment: @AAD - answer was edited.